# How to Replace Strings in a Text File VB6

Tags: vb6

i have a problem right now. Im using textfile as my database. Here is the format of my Strings inside the textfile.

01/Alarm1/01:00:00

01/Alarm2/02:00:00

01/Alarm3/03:00:00

For example i just want to rename the Alarm2 but it will keep the 01 on the beginning and the time on it. Thanks for help guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find an example on which you can rely on in order to:

1. read a text file
2. update its content
3. write it back

Hope this will help you.

```
Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
Dim TS As TextStream
Dim TempS As String
Dim Final As String
Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile("mydata.txt", ForReading)
Do Until TS.AtEndOfStream
    TempS = TS.ReadLine
    'if TempS contains Alarm2 => rename Alarm
    Final = Final & TempS & vbCrLf
Loop
TS.Close

Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile("mydata.txt", ForWriting, True)
    TS.Write Final
TS.Close
Set TS = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
```

Comment: sir can i ask what will i do on the line that has commented? just a sample on replacing of string. thanks

Comment: Check the documentation for the `Replace` function over here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/bt3szac5(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Affirmative, something like that should work: `TempS=Replace(TempS, "Alarm2", "AlarmChanged")`

Comment: Thanks! I found it very useful. But I implemented it using:  `TempS = TS.ReadAll
Final = Replace(TempS, "Alarm2", "Alarm") `  because it is much faster in large files

Answer (score 0):

- open txt file;

loop begin

- get the string(by rows) - lets consider it is 'someStr'
- you can use NewStr = Replace(someStr,"Alarm","Warning")
- write NewStr to a new file

loop end

close both files